# ionic three display one div at a time

Tags: ionic-framework

have divided my form into divs on one ionic html page want to display one at a time, navigate until submit any help, my form is somehow like this, the first should display  by default but the other divs should be displayed on clicking next

```
 <div id="formPart1">
   <ion-row>
        <label>select date</label>
        <ion-input type="date" ng-model="date"></ion-input>
        <button ion-button full  ng-click="showNext()">Next</button>
   </ion-row>
</div>
  <div id="formPart2">
  <ion-row>
        <label>select date</label>
        <ion-input type="name" ng-model="name"></ion-input>
   </ion-row>
 </div>
```

Comment: I can't find div tag in code?

Comment: sorry let me edit so they can display

Answer (score 0):

So, First of all you have to write the code like this

```
<div id="formPart1">
   <ion-row>
    <ion-label>select date</label>
    <ion-input type="date" [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-input>
    <button ion-button full  (click)="showNext()">Next</button>
   </ion-row>
</div>

<div id="formPart2" [hidden]="!YOUR_VARIABLE">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-label>select date</label>
    <ion-input type="name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

in the show `showNext()` method you have to make the variable true, like this

```
showNext() {
    this.YOUR_GLOBAL_VARIABLE = true
}
```

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: Glad that it helps you

Answer (score 0):

In this case, i suggest you to use ion-slides. Distribute form elements to the slides. and lock swipe on page load and only change to next slide on Next button click.

Do this to lock swiping

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ServicePage');
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
}
```

and on Next button click

```
goToSlide(slideNo) {   


    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
    this.slides.slideTo(slideNo, 500);
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }
```